# Android app development: How to keep sending data over the same socket(same port on server)?

Tags: android, sockets

I'm coding an app where the user can input a text message and send it over UDP. My MainActivity consists of a page where the user inputs the ip address of the server and the port. As soon as the user presses on the connect button, it will create a socket and send an empty packet. Also when the user presses the connect button, the SecondActivity will start. The SecondActivity consists of a EditText input field, where text can be inserted and sent. I want the messages sent over the same UDP socket created in the MainActivity. I got a separate class for the UDP client.

MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect;

    Udpclient udpclient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ip);
        editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_port);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Connect_button);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

            String ip = editTextAddress.getText().toString();
            int port =  Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString());

            udpclient = new Udpclient(ip,port);
            udpclient.start();

            Intent intent = new   Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("ip", ip);
            intent.putExtra("port", port);

            startActivity(intent);

            }




        });




    }
}
```

Udpclient

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Udpclient extends Thread {


    String ipaddress;
    int port;

    DatagramSocket socket;
    InetAddress address;

    public Udpclient(String addr, int prt) {
        ipaddress = addr;
        port = prt;


    }


    public void run() {


        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            address = InetAddress.getByName(ipaddress);

            // send request
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            DatagramPacket packet =
                    new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();

            }
        }


    }


}
```

SecondActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int port;
    String ip;

    EditText editTextInput;
    Button buttonSend;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        editTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_input);
        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("ip");
        int number = intent.getIntExtra("port", 0);
        port = number;
        ip = name;

        //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //textView.setText(name);

        //TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //textView2.setText(String.valueOf(number));

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }


        });
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what isn't working. What's the problem? Also note that _"How can I code this?"_ questions is potentially to be closed.

Comment: @Onik The problem is: how can I send packets over the same UDP socket, because now  a new socket will be created.

Comment: If you want to open the socket and remain opened, then set `socket.setKeepAlive(true);` when creating a socket in Android. Then you can send and/or receive data without having to connect again

Comment: Making `Udpclient` to be a [singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/2179/singleton/15446/singleton-java#t=201610301719330495926) allows you to get its instance from different objects (`Activities`).

Comment: @Onik Is it also possible to create a singleton of the socket object? socket = new DatagramSocket(); I want to use that variable in the SecondActivity.

Comment: _"Is it also possible to create a singleton of the socket object?"_ Only if you're a Oracle engineer that's been developing new Java APIs.

Comment: @Onik How do I get my SecondActivity to use the same socket variable from the Udpclient class?

Comment: @Onik Could you please help me out?

Comment: Your question is broad. I've already helped you pointing to the right direction. Read and understand the topic, then come here and ask a narrower question. No one here is going to such a broad work for you.

Comment: @Onik I understand, is it possible to create a singleton when the class extends a Thread?

Comment: _"is it possible to create a singleton when the class extends a Thread?"_ Yes. You can make any object to be a singleton. Singleton pattern simply means that there is the only instance of the object in memory, compare to non-singleton objects for which a new instance is created in memory each time you use `new` operator.

Comment: @Onik I have created a singleton of the Udpclient, but it keeps creating new sockets when I send a message :(